# How to load DLL which is having one form and i want to load the DLL in other project which is creating exe file?

Tags: winforms, dll

I am creating one class library prpject A and it is having one winform. After building this project it will give the DLL name A.

Now I want to use the DLL name A in windows form project B. And I want to launch the form which is created in class library project A in this windows project B.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: A *solution* can contain more than one project.  Right-click the solution node in the Solution Explorer window, Add, Existing Project and select the A project.  Now you can add a project reference to A in your B project and make changes to A if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple,

Now you have the `A.dll`. Add this A.dll as a project reference to your `project B`. Add the namespace statement to the class in project B from where you are trying to access form in A.dll

```
using A;
```

Now you can access the form in A.dll from project B directly,

```
FormInA form = new FormInA();
form.Show();
```